# Using JQuery .load() with .hide() and .show() on page startup

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to show a `div` on page startup:

```
$("#mydiv").hide().show("slow");
```

This will make the `div` appear with a slow animation on page startup (page load / refresh)

However, if, on page startup (page load / refresh), I want to insert HTML from another file into this `div` before this animation starts I try to do this:

```
$("#mydiv").load("myPage.html");
$("#mydiv").hide().show("slow");
```

When I do this, the animation no longer works on startup (page load / refresh). How can I load html from another file and still have the animation work on page startup (page load / refresh)?

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#mydiv').load('myPage.html', function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
});
```

in your css add

```
#mydiv { 
   display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Upvote. Tested this method and its the easiest i think.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use CSS for initial hiding of your `div`

```css
#mydiv { display: none }
```

and then you can show it

```
$("#mydiv").load("myPage.html", function() {
    $(this).show(600);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the show part as a callback to the load:

```
$("#mydiv").hide().load("myPage.html", function(){
    $(this).show('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to hide the page, load the content and then show the div. You can simply do using the second argument (`complete`) of [`.load(url[, data][, complete])`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#myDiv').load('...', function() {
    // gets executed when the content is loaded
    $(this).show('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way.

You an do something like this using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "myPage.html",
        cache: false
    }).done(function (html) {
        $("#myDiv").append(html);
        $("#myDiv").hide().show("slow");
    });
```

This ensure the page is called before the animation begins!